Squelch breaks but no sound
I am new to ham radio. I was trying to listen in to my locally used frequencies, which I looked up.
I can tune the freq in the 440 range on my radio. When I first tuned the frequency, I could tell there was chatter because my squelch would break, but it was just a buzzing sound.
The frequency listed a "tone" which I figured out was the CTCS code, which I set on my radio for receive on that freq. Now my radio just lights up when the squelch breaks on that freq but I don't hear anything.
What am I doing wrong?

"440 range": I'll assume you mean 440 MHz, is that right? (There's also non-amateur radio allocations in the 440 kHz band, so being specific here is necessary. Generally, frequencies (not "freqs" when you communicate in speaking or written, usually!) have a physical unit; omitting that makes it necessary to "guess" things, so try to keep the physical unit around :) )

"The frequency listed a "tone": hm, what listed that where? Do you happen to have a link or name of source? Might help us assess what that means.

What we can tell you is that the CTCSS is successfully suppressing the output of your receiver, which means two things: 1. it works! and 2. your interpretation of what that "tone" meant was incorrect (or the transmissions you try to listen to aren't covered by what you've read).

oh, and hey: Welcome here! Good to have you around.

Yes, welcome! Kindly edit your question and tell us what model of Baofeng that you have.

Try to turn up the volume on your radio.

If squelch opens but there is no sound, one of the following is possible:

You have the volume turned all the way down or your speakers are otherwise not working
You have tone squelch enabled but the ctcss (or dcs, etc.) doesn't match or is missing in the received signal (maybe it's noise TSQL successfully blocked?)
Someone transmitted without audio or with low audio

If you hear buzzing, the following are possible:

Your radio is in the wrong mode (AM/FM/SSB)
Two FM stations transmitted at the same time on the same frequency
Your radio has poor adjacent channel isolation and you are hearing leakage from a neighboring frequency
You are off frequency from the channel
The other station transmitting is off frequency
You are hearing some other kind of interference

If it is more of a hum than a buzz, the following are possible:

You are hearing the CTCSS tone which is suppose to be "subaudible" but may be set too loud
You are hearing 60hz hum from power line leakage or a ground loop
If the frequency goes up and down slightly or shifts slowly, and either you or the transmitter is in a vehicle, it could be alternator noise; other similar power supply noise is possible even out of a vehicle.

A buzz could also be a digital mode, but that's usually more of a screech.
If you are on an FM repeater and you hear a voice that is kinda buzzy and sometimes cuts out completely, the transmitter may be over modulating their audio (i.e., talking too loud) which clips and sometimes causes the repeater to lose the lock on the signal.  This is kind of a combination of "buzz" and "no audio" :)  Under some conditions, this can be difficult to distinguish from being off frequency.  (In both cases, the signal is clipped because either the audio or the radio signal is partially and intermittently outside the appropriate pass band.)
Some of these are more obvious than others and may be in the background of a signal with or without voice.  Some of these can be distinguished with some experience.

Welcome to the hobby.  If this is a new radio, it has already been suggested that you may simply have the volume down.  Otherwise, so you don't get frustrated just searching for frequencies, go to radioreference.com and look for amateur radio frequencies and repeaters near you. That will give you what you need to program your radio to so you can be sure to be successful. Reach out to your local Clubs and they can help you.
73 de WB4CDR Clint Jax, FL
